# Formulas's deduction from the generating function of Hermite polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, generating-functions, hermite-polynomials

In the book "Essential Mathematical Methods for Physicists" comes the following problem that I am trying to solve:
[image: Problem]

at first I could see that the first formula that is given as an answer is wrong since the hermite polynomial $ H_4 (x) $ does not match with the known since:

$\begin{align*}
H_{2n}(x)&=(-1)^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{n}(-1)^{2s}(2x)^{2s}\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=(-1)^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{n}\left[(-1)^{2}\right]^s\left[(2x)^{2}\right]^s\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=(-1)^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{n}\left[1\right]^s\left[4x^2\right]^s\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}\\
H_{2n}(x)&=(-1)^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{n}\left[4x^2\right]^s\cfrac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}\\
H_{2(2)}(x)&=(-1)^{2}\sum_{s=0}^{2}\left(4x^2\right)^s\cfrac{(2\cdot 2)!}{(2s)!(2-s)!}\\
H_{4}(x)&=(1)\sum_{s=0}^{2}\left(4x^2\right)^s\cfrac{(4)!}{(2s)!(2-s)!}\\
H_{4}(x)&=\sum_{s=0}^{2}\left(4x^2\right)^s\cfrac{24}{(2s)!(2-s)!}\\
H_{4}(x)&=(4x^2)^{0}\cfrac{24}{(2\cdot 0)!(2-0)!}+(4x^2)^{1}\cfrac{24}{(2\cdot 1)!(2-1)!}+(4x^2)^{2}\cfrac{24}{(2\cdot 2)!(2-2)!}\\
H_{4}(x)&=(1)\cfrac{24}{(0)!(2)!}+(4x^2)\cfrac{24}{(2)!(1)!}+(16x^4)\cfrac{24}{(4)!(0)!}\\
H_{4}(x)&=(1)\cfrac{24}{(1)(2)}+(4x^2)\cfrac{24}{(2)(1)}+(16x^4)\cfrac{24}{(24)(1)}\\
H_{4}(x)&=12+(4x^2)(12)+(16x^4)\\
H_{4}(x)&=12+48x^2+16x^4\\
H_{4}(x)&=16x^4+48x^2+12 \\
\end{align*}$

But the real $H_4(x)$ is $H_4(x)=16x^4-48x^2+12$ so the $H_{2n}$ formula is wrong.
But trying to find errors in the formula for $ H_ {2n + 1} $ I did not find any for the polynomials 1,3,5 so I think that this formula is correct.

If the generating function of the hermite polynomials is $g (x, t) = e^{-t^2 + 2tx} = \sum_{n = 0} ^ {\infty}H_n (x) \cfrac{t ^ n}{n!} $

How can the formula for $H_{2n + 1}$ be derived?

I tried using the formula $H_n(x)=\sum_{s=0}^{[n/2]}(-1)^s\cfrac{n!}{(n-2s)!s!}(2x)^{n-2s}$ (
which is just the equation 13.40 that mentions the problem) substituting in the value of 2n + 1 but couldn't deduce anything, as there were terms that I couldn't adjust to look like the one the book asks for an answer. Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: You may find it useful to compare your books expressions with those given on the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression). Note that your book uses the physicist convention, so you may safely ignore the $He_n(x)$ expressions.

Comment: Please do not make such dramatic edits after the question has been answered.  Edits which invalidate the answers which have already been provided are disrespectful towards the folk who have taken the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $H_{2n}(x)$, the upper limit of their equation 13.40 is $\lceil (2n)/2\rceil=n$ and so the sum is $$H_{2n}(x)=\sum_{s=0}^n (-1)^s \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2s)!s!}(2x)^{2n-2s}.$$ This is a descending sum, since it starts with highest power $(2x)^{2n}$ and terminates with $(2x)^0=1$. To make it ascending, we relabel $s\to n-s$ and so obtain

$$H_{2n}(x)=\sum_{s=0}^n (-1)^{n-s} \frac{(2n)!}{(2s)!(n-s)!}(2x)^{2s}.$$ This disagrees with the stated expansion in that it has $(-1)^s$ instead of $(-1)^{2s}$. Given that the latter would equal $1$ for all integers, though, I'm inclined to chalk that up to a typo. (By contrast, the case for odd $n$ does seem correct.)